# Excel Finding Value Based On Criteria

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula, excel-2010

i have multiple columns in my excel spreadsheet (DOLLAR, Date, Year), i am trying to get the values in column DOLLAR, if the DATE is greater than 01 Jan 2014, and the YEAR is 2014.

I tried sumproduct, countifs, if, match and even combinations of them but i cant seem to get the value of DOLLAR based on the criteria. how would i go about doing this? i am still a bit new to this so i don't quite know all the functions yet.

i have something like this right now, also  all the DOLLAR value that meets the criteria will all be summed up.

```
=IF('CDT DWGS-2014'!F:F=2014,IF('CDT DWGS-2014'!Q:Q>DATEVALUE("01-Jan-2014"),"GET DOLLAR VALUE",0),0)
```

Thank you

Comment: So you want the **sum** of all Dollar values within the year that is greater than that specific date?

Comment: yes, preferably between two dates (Example: 01-Jan-14 and 01-Feb-14) But you are correct. i would like the sum of all dollar values between these dates

Comment: Ok, posting solution now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, given your extra comments, I also tried to make it a bit more robust for you, so suppose, in your sheet you had:

```
A1 = Start Date
B1 = End Date
```

And in your **CDT DWGS-2014** sheet, the Dollar amounts were in column A and the dates were in column B, You could use the following formula:

```
=SUMIFS('CDT DWGS-2014'!A:A,'CDT DWGS-2014'!B:B,">="&A1,'CDT DWGS-2014'!B:B,"<="&B1)
```

This could be made simpler, but this should do the trick.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula. Column A, B and C are for DOLLAR, Date and Year respectively.

=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A11,--(B2:B11>DATE(2014,1,1)),--(C2:C11=2014))